# Why should government bonds have been a part of FSB rules on repo markets?

Tags: macroeconomics, banking, financial-economics, bonds

Since the financial crash, reforms have been made by the FSB, I would like to know why there is the opinion that government bonds should have been part of FSB rules on repo markets

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what you mean? The FSB itself doesn’t really have rules, it sets out best practice standards. What part of those standards should apply to sovereign bonds? As a wild guess, are you talking about minimum haircuts? Can you point to someone who has expressed the opinion you’d like details on?